# Attributes options connected

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Is there a way to "bound" two different attributes to the same attributes options?

I have two attributes with dropdowns, but I want them to share same options. Now every time I want to add a new option or edit existing one I have to do it twice.

Please let me know what is the best way to achieve such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you create the second attribute with a custom source model.
[Here is an example](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) of creating such an attribute.
In that example you need to change the method `getAllOptions` and make it read the options of your other attribute.
Let's say your first attribute has the code `some_attribute` you method needs to look like this:

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = false){
    return Mage::getModel('eav/config')
             ->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'some_attribute')
             ->getAllOptions($withEmpty);
}
```